# Отправка bytes или base64 в телеграм бот

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Можно ли в телеграм бот отправить картинку в bytes или base64, задача обусловлена архитектурой приложения, на одном сервисе работает хук с телеграма, он принимает картинку и передает в другой сервис, который, обрабатывает картинку и возвращает её первому сервису в base64. Сохранить картинку возможности нет. Работаю с python 3.

Comment: Ну в байтах точно можно

Comment: Да и в целом думаю найти что-то для конвертации base64 не сложно

Comment: В том то и дело, что сложно, получается base64 возвращается как строка, надо как-то ее конвертировать в base64 так, чтобы она не изменилась и потом в bytes, что-то вообще ничего толкового найти не могу.